# Making a complex shape like an octagon with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a octagon, with an inner octagon within in, the inner octagon will be divided in sections, with each section forming a new shape with names in it.

The octagon will also have trees at its edges. Any help is appreciated.

All have managed to do is create an octagon with the css below

```
#octagon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
#octagon:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 29px solid green;
  border-left: 29px solid #eee;
  border-right: 29px solid #eee;
}
#octagon:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 29px solid green;
  border-left: 29px solid #eee;
  border-right: 29px solid #eee;
}
```

See image for clarity. [Octagon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx2NZ.jpg)

Comment: Please include your HTML in the question along with the JS/css you've written in an attempt to achieve your goal.

Comment: Not in pure css, no. I mean probably you could, but it would be 100 easier with js

Comment: Please can you give more insights on how to achieve this with js

Comment: https://css-doodle.com/ Try using this

Comment: to add the trees you can use pseudo-elements ::before and ::after with SVGs

Answer (score 1):

To position other shapes inside the parent shape, you can use absolute positioning like this:

```css
 .div1 {
    position:relative;
    background:blue;
    height:200px;width:200px;
    clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
    }
   
   .other-shape {
   position:absolute;
   left:50px;top:50px;
   width:100px;height:100px;background:red;
   }
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="other-shape">
  </div>
</div>
```